# Extension YiiMaill (Swiftmailer) can't send SMTP from gmail

Tags: php, email, yii, swiftmailer, yii-extensions

I've a PHP application that's running with **Yii Framework** and it's using the **YiiMail** extension that's is based in **Swiftmailer**.

My application was working perfectly yesterday, but today the follow error was launched:

**fsockopen():** *SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed*

My Yii app config:

```
'mail' => 
  array('class' => 'application.extensions.yii-mail.YiiMail',
        'transportType' => 'smtp', 
        'transportOptions' => array(
             'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com', 
             'username' => '**@gmail.com', 
             'password' => '***', 
             'port' => '465', 
             'encryption'=>'tls' ), 
         'viewPath' => 'application.views.mail', 
         'logging' =>false, 
         'dryRun' => false
 )
```

---

**ANSWER: A FAST SOLUTION**

My app is running in Windows, so I did a fast configuration to solve this problem at moment.

I did a configuration with **sendmail** and it enable into my php.ini file.

Ps: The main problem is if you have many apps running in the same php. How don't  this problem to me, it's is stand alone application, I just did.

Something like this:

**sendmail.ini**

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587
#default_domain = gmail.com it's is not necessary
auth_username= your gmail@gmail.com
auth_password=your password
```

**php.ini**

```
[mail function]
sendmail_path = "path to sendmail installation"
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587
```

Comment: you should show, the settings you put in your switfmailer config.

Comment: @MarkRyanOrosa, I was forget it, sorry! But I already update it.

Comment: is that Yii2 or just Yii?

Comment: It's is 1.1. version! That is a old application, that was working fine, but today this problem happening.

Comment: hope , you have to remove the comment for the line of `extension=php_openssl.dll` in the `php.ini` file

Comment: @rch the mail was working perfectly in my app, and now stopping running. My PHP config is ok, OpenSSL extension is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your current config was previously working, then suddenly stopped. Consider looking into the following:

- [Generating an APP password for a gmail account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833)
- [Enabling Less SecureApps settings for your gmail account](https://www.google.com/settings/u/1/security/lesssecureapps)

I have encountered a similar problem before, enabling Less Secure Apps, then when I set [2 Step Verification](https://www.google.com/settings/u/1/security/lesssecureapps) for my google account, it stopped working.

Then generating an APP password, did the trick!

Comment: I did these two steps.

Comment: let me know how it goes.

Comment: I did a configuration with sendmail and it enable into my php.ini file.

Comment: I'VE POSTED A FAST SOLUTION IN THE SAME QUESTION POST!

Answer (score 0):

This is my working smtp settings in my Yii2 project:
common/config/main-local.php

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bd-sys',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                'username' => '******@gmail.com',
                'password' => '******',
                'port' => 587,
                'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: I don't have this options to put in my configuration. I'm using Yii 1 and no exists that option to include in my config file. : (